# Import of function causes triggering DOMContentLoaded twice

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

In file1.js I have:

```
export function1() {}
function2() {}
```

```
window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    console.log('dom loaded');
    function2();
}, { once: true } )
```

In file2.js I have:

```
import { function1 } from "./file1".
```

The import in file2 makes triggering DOMContentLoaded twice. I mean "dom loaded" is logged twice, and when I remove import from file2, it is logged only once. How to fix it? I need to use function1 in file2, but function2 should be called only once and now it's called twice.

Comment: Are both imported from the same module root? (the same `<script>` tag, be it as content or `src`)? If they are not, then this would probably be expected behaviour. If they are, the imported file should indeed only be executed once and its exports defined only once.

Comment: I don't know if understand correctly. file1.js is imported to main.js and file2.js is imported to homepage.js and both files (main.js and homepage.js) are loaded on the home page and this is where problem with triggering domconteloaded occurs.

Comment: If your files don't share a `root`, they are presumed to be separate instances. On your homepage, try `<script type="module">import "index.js"; import "homepage.js";</script>` and see if your issue goes away. Once they are part of the same "module", they should execute only once. If they are loaded as separate scripts, they are separate modules and don't share imports etc...

Comment: ok, so I imported main.js to homepage.js and excluded main.js from loading on the homepage and it's correct now. Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the code of how the files are loaded in the page